# I2C and interrupts

Tags: arduino, microcontroller

I'm making a quadcopter with SparkFun ESP32 Thing module and using MPU9255 Waveshare IMU.

It looks like when I'm reading PWM signals from RC receiver with interrupts (6 interrupts for 6 chanels) I2C fails after some time. I am using interrupt over MPU9250 either (but not the DMP module, just sync for accel and gyro data). I am not sure if the connection fails, MPU9250 or ESP32.
It looks like this:
After 10-50sec, MPU9250 fails, and MPUs interrupt works at 8kHz (instead of 1,6kHz), and values wont change. 
No idea what is happening ;/ Anyone?
Without interrupts, I2C works fine...

Comment: Could this be a baud rate issue? Have you tried with different rates?

Comment: You mean I2C speed? Ill try slower rates (its now 400kHz, maximum of mpu). But even if there is a problem with rate I would like to avoid changing it (due to slower response)...

Comment: Still the same issue?

Comment: It seems stable now (200kHz rate). Not sure if I can go higher?

Comment: Try to find a right rate for your application, usually solves the problem.

Comment: It works, thanks. I just regret it is 300kHz not 400kHz :( Got 1,3kHz instead of 1,6kHz gyro update rate, but at least its reliable :).

Comment: Unfortunately problem came back... Its just more rare.

Comment: Hmm can't really answer this without seeing the connections and code. Faulty connections can also add to this problem.

Comment: Nothing works, and I am sure that connections are fine... ESP32 has internal pullups and ive tested several different pins. So no hardware problem IMO...
But it seems like its fine NOW... Dont know how I repaired it... Weird...

Answer (score 0):

Your ISRs must save and restore ALL registers and flags that are used.  If you are calling any external functions from your ISRs, there could be reentrancy issues.  Without a look at the code, that's the best I can offer.

Comment: I had similar issues with a self balancing bot of mine, just figuring out the right baud rate fixed this issue for me.